# Change image attributes on listbox change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox, attributes

I want to display an album gallery that would be selected from selectbox for each separate folders.

the HTML code below:

```
<select name="album" id="album" onChange="changeimage();">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Select an album gallery...</option>
    <option value="1">RC</option>
    <option value="2">MR</option>
    <option value="3">CD</option>
    <option value="4">KP</option>
    <option value="5">SH</option>
</select>

<!-- Display default images on page load -->
<img src="images/rC/img1.jpg" id="img1" title="RC" alt="Image1"/> 
<img src="images/rC/img2.jpg" id="img2" title="RC" alt="Image2"/> 
<img src="images/rC/img3.jpg" id="img3" title="RC" alt="Image3"/> 
<img src="images/rC/img4.jpg" id="img4" title="RC" alt="Image4"/> 
<img src="images/rC/img5.jpg" id="img5" title="RC" alt="Image5"/>
```

the jQuery code as below:

```
function changeimage() {
    "use strict";
    var folder;
    var img_title;

    if ($("select#album").val() === 1) { 
        folder = "rC/img"; img_title = "RC";
    } else if ($("select#album").val() === 2) {
        folder = "mR/img"; img_title = "MR";
    } else if ($("select#album").val() === 3) { 
        folder = "cD/img"; img_title = "CD";
    } else if ($("select#album").val() === 4) { 
        folder = "kP/img"; img_title = "KP";
    } else if ($("select#album").val() === 5) {
        folder = "sH/img"; img_title = "SH";
    }

    $("img#img1").attr({ src: "images/" + folder + "1.jpg", title: img_title, alt: "Image1" });
    $("img#img2").attr({ src: "images/" + folder + "2.jpg", title: img_title, alt: "Image2" });
    $("img#img3").attr({ src: "images/" + folder + "3.jpg", title: img_title, alt: "Image3" });
    $("img#img4").attr({ src: "images/" + folder + "4.jpg", title: img_title, alt: "Image4" });
    $("img#img5").attr({ src: "images/" + folder + "5.jpg", title: img_title, alt: "Image5" });
}
```

Comment: So... What can I do? What is your advice?

Comment: because it's not working...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) return content of `value` attribute of selected option that is `string`. Problem of your code is in condition.

```
if ($("select#album").val() === 1)
```

When you used `===` in if condition that means should type of values be equal. While `1` isn't equal to `"1"`. You need to use

```
if ($("select#album").val() === "1")
// or
if ($("select#album").val() == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you bro Muhammed ;) Can you say me how about include a folder instead of type manually like the js code above 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg etc... I don't want this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you are awasome. but I donnot want to use selected option text for album. because I have lots of albums and they start with the same name. So how about to work on id s of selected. for example: I have -> faces -> facebo -> facebok folders... How it works on them for the first two chars you coded.

Comment: no no... under images folder I have (face folder), (faces folder), (facebo folder), (facebok folder)... etc. not subdirectory... so your code before you wrote me works but my album folders have the same names for the first two chars >>> fa..

Comment: however the same thing about manual type.. how can I do dynamically add < option > tag in a folder to number of pictures in HTML code. If album folder have 25 pictures I cannot add for each albums 25 or more < option > tag..

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. I solved it with your codes and with my previous codes.